# conditional expression and expansion

Tags: bash, shell, control-flow

I don't seem to understand how to "test" the conditional operators [[ and [.  I tried using various form such as

```
echo [[a=a]]

[[a=a]]
echo $?
```

and some other things

I want to see what they return, to test some comparisons. How do you expand them, or execute them?

Comment: Answers belong in the answer box below.

Comment: I'll do that now

Comment: I hate posting an answer to my own question so I tried to leave it open

Comment: I suggest to think a little bit more next time, before posting such an elementary question. As you see, often answers come on their own.

Comment: @rubixibuc: Actually, answering your own question is something encouraged here (as unintuitive as it may seem). But I agree with enzotib, you did not really pick the most complex question to post ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rubixibuc is right, spaces are necessary.
You can test it with:

```
if [ "`whoami`" == "root" ]; then echo "To err is human...to really foul up requires the root password"; else echo "not telling any jokes"; fi
```

Answer (score 3):

I didn't mean to post an answer right away but solved it after thinking about it more.  There needs to a space between either the [[ or [ and the next token.

here's how you would test it.

```
[[ a = a ]]
```

or

```
[ a = a ]
```

then

```
echo $?
```

Comment: This is correct. `[` and `[[` are commands, and just as one must put a space after `echo` or `ls`, a space must follow these.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Nitpick: `[` is a command (and so if you don't put a space after it you get the `[a=a]` command), `[[` is a keyword (but you still need the space after it, otherwise you get the `[[a=a]]` command).